# Golang Defer to act on caller / outer function?

Tags: go

Is it possible to `defer` to the end of an outer function?

```
// normal transaction
func dbStuff(){
    db.Begin()
    ...
    db.Commit()
}

// normal transaction w/ defer
func dbStuff(){
    db.Begin()
    defer db.Commit()
    ...
}
```

**Is this possible?**

```
// can you defer to caller / outer function?
func dbStuff(){
    db.Trans()
    ...
}

// will Commit() when dbStuff() returns
func (db Db) Trans(){
    db.Begin()
    defer db.Commit() // to caller/outer function
}
```

Answer (score 9):

According to the specification, it's *not* possible:

> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is **deferred to the moment the surrounding function returns**, either because the surrounding function executed a return statement, reached the end of its function body, or because the corresponding goroutine is panicking.

(emphasis mine)

**Update**: Apart from that, it would not be a good idea either – one of the strengths of Go is "what you see is what you get". Deferring functions from inner functions to outer functions would create 'invisible' changes in your control flow.

Answer (score 9):

This might be helpful.

```
func main() {
    defer greet()() 
    fmt.Println("Some code here...")
}

func greet() func() {
    fmt.Println("Hello!")
    return func() { fmt.Println("Bye!") } // this will be deferred
}
```

Output:

```
Hello!
Some code here...
Bye!
```

Reference: https://asanchez.dev/blog/defer-golang-on-entry/

Comment: I like how this dodges the "implicit changes in your code" argument in  @publysher's answer, since it differs visually from an usual defer with the double function call. 
This should be the accepted answer!